# Why is color-coding lost when copying text from the Alloy tool and pasting to Powerpoint?

Tags: alloy

The Alloy tool nicely color-codes reserved words, as illustrated here:

[image: Color-coded Alloy text]

When I copy text from the Alloy tool and paste the text into Powerpoint, I lose the color-coding, as shown here:

[image: Not color-coded Alloy text]

So sad.

Is there a way to copy the text such that it can be pasted into Powerpoint (or Word) without losing the color-coding (formatting)?

Comment: you could include your code as a screenshot. If you're ready to use Latex to make your slides/documents, there's a lot of style file available providing syntax highlighting for Alloy. Here's one : https://github.com/Angtrim/alloy-latex-highlighting

Comment: Hi @Loïc Gammaitoni, yes I could include the code as a screenshot, but my preference, if possible, is to paste text into Powerpoint because text is easy to modify.

Comment: file a feature request at https://github.com/alloytools/org.alloytools.alloy/issues (or better, make a PR! :-)

Comment: Hi @Peter Kriens, okay I added a feature request. Thanks!